# PyCharm printing 'True' when importing nltk

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, nltk

I have the following code running in Pycharm using Anaconda package manager with Python 3.6

```
print('before')

import nltk

print('after')
```

And I am getting this result in the console of PyCharm.

```
before
True
after
```

When I run this in the command line of Python output is normal as expected.

It appears the import statement of NLTK module is printing True. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

I have already tried Invalidate Caches / Restart option in PyCharm

Comment: I have pycharm 2017.2.3 and python 3.6.0 installed on my mac 10.12.6 and cannot reproduce this. `nltk` is installed by pip while python installed by pyenv. Maybe sth wrong with conda.

Comment: It's not a huge issue as it doesn't show in regular Python console, just a bit strange. Causes about a second hang time too. Tried updating conda too.

Comment: You could try monkey patching the builtin `print` function, replacing it with a function that will raise an exception so you can see where the `print` is happening during the import call. Or maybe it could launch a debugger (e.g. `pdb.set_trace()`).

Comment: I just tried this in PyCharm 2017.3 EAP 2, Anaconda (built July 23), Python 3.6, nltk 3.2.4 in a Conda env. And I'm just getting 'before' 'after', I don't see True anywhere. If you run this code in the Python console in PyCharm, do you see 'True' printed?

Comment: Which version of nltk are you running? `print(nltk.__version__)`?

Comment: Could you try print(os.path.abspath(nltk.__file__)) to see where you are importing nltk version from.

Comment: nltk version 3.2.5 (was on 3.2.4 and upgrades, still occuring).

nltk being imported from anaconda3

Comment: With that part of `print(os.path.abspath(nltk.__file__)`, I wanted to see the exact location of where it is loading nltk to see if there is any funkiness there.

Comment: apologies.

C:\Users\Andy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py

Comment: Is there a `/` after the `nltk` or is it `nltk_init_.py` ?

Comment: my bad. it is """ nltk\\_\_init__.py """

Comment: Have you tried @Blckknght's suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got so sick of using Anaconda, that I ended up uninstalling it and just installed Python clean from python.org and the issue went away in PyCharm